# Universal Turing machine simulating the null Turing machine?

Tags: turing-machines

The definition of the universal Turing machine is

$$
U(\langle M \rangle,p)=M(p)
$$

where U is a universal Turing taking two inputs $\langle M \rangle$, the binary encoding of a Turing machine, and $p$ a binary program.

What happens in the case where we feed the null Turing machine to the UTM.

$$
U(0,p)=?U(p)?
$$

Will this give out the outputs that are specific to the given formulation of the UTM being run?

Also, is there any kind of general properties of $U(p)$ between the universal Turing machines? My intuition tells me $U(p)$ must be the same answer for all UTMs and all $p$, but I would like confirmation.

Comment: There is no null Turing machine. If the input is malformed, then we don't particularly care about what the UTM outputs.

Comment: Given any "reasonable" encoding $\langle . \rangle$, $0$ is just the index of some machine. Which one depends on the specific encoding (there are infinitely many). Nothing special about it.

Comment: @Yuval I see. Then my question should read a universal Turing machine simulating itself U(U,p) = U(p)? This would be equivalent to the null Turing machine as I meant it in my question.

Answer (score -1):

Yes...your intuition to the problem approach is correct.Here are the properties from which you can gain much more clarity:
[Unsolvable Problems Stanford-Stanford University](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs103/cs103.1142/lectures/21/Small21.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjJtdSis-H5AhXER2wGHfzpBFoQFnoECAwQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3P7do2_AED5SUz5jhJaqs8)